# Hose converter between Dewalt Saw and Shop Vac

Tags: power-tools, tools, cutting, miter-saw

I recently bought [DEWALT DW715 15-Amp 12-Inch Single-Bevel Compound Miter Saw](http://smile.amazon.com/DEWALT-DW715-12-Inch-Single-Bevel-Compound/dp/B000ASBCK4?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o07_s00) and was hoping to hook it up to my [Shop-Vac 12-Gallon 6-Peak HP Shop Vacuum](http://www.lowes.com/pd_549713-20097-5926211_1z11p8g__?productId=50159065&pl=1). So far, I've been unsuccessful at finding a converter piece. The descriptions read 1.25" for the hose out of the back of the saw and 1.5" for the shop vac hose. Can anyone tell me where I might be able to find the piece I need?

Comment: Woodworking supply stores have adapters. Including some adapters that will work for tools whose dust port isn't round; I've been meaning to get one of those to work with my belt sander.

Comment: Worst case, multiple wraps of duct tape on the saw. Fancy version: some kind of abs/pvc/... piping with a slit cut out of it so it fits perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a `Universal Hose Adapter` that can be purchased at most hardware and tool suppliers (big box stores like Home Deport will also carry them).

They look like this picture.

[image]

You would purchase a 1.5" adapter and then cut off the sections until you reach the smaller size.

I've found that these do not fit tightly. You will need to use hose clamps to secure it, but try it first. Sometimes when the vac is running it's enough vacuum to hold them together firmly.

Comment: Tape can be wrapped to get the final size adjustment.

Comment: I've also seen seen homebrew solutions involving a couple of holesawed pieces glued back to back, one sized for each fitting.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to put a hood or box with a fitting for your hose behind the saw.  If you really want to do a good job set up the table the saw sits upon as a down-draft style table as well, because not all the dust is thrown back, some is thrown downward off the edge of the blade closest to the operator.  To do both you'd probably need a legit dust collector machine, as your shop-vac likely won't support collection at both points.